# Arabic Language not inserting into Oracle Database from PHP code

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I wrote a function in PHP that generated SQL queries and insert records into Oracle Database by using PHP-OCI. But after insertion is done and I check into the Oracle table, the Arabic data turns into "???" marks but when I manually run the Insert query inside SQL Editor then the Arabic language showing fine. The UTF8 enabled in Oracle, I think something wrong with the PHP OCI side.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your connection to the DB, you should [specify a character set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-pconnect.php):

```
$c = oci_pconnect('cj', 'cj', 'mdt/orclpdb1', 'AL32UTF8');
```

This could also be set with the environment variable NLS_LANG.

See https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html

Similarly a character set should be specified in whatever tool you are checking the data with.